# Guardando carrito de compra en base de datos laravel

Tags: php, laravel

buen dia comunidad.

estoy desarrollando un sistema de carrito de compra con laravel y la siguiente libreria: `https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart`

pero tengo un inconveniente o mas bien un duda, cuando quiero finalizar la compra.

el metodo store me pide un idenficador "$identifier" el cual no se de donde obtenerlo.

segun la documentacion este "$identifier" seria el nombre de usuario o el id,

```
Cart::store('username');
```

pero si utilizo alguno de los 2 y el mismo usuario vuelve a realizar una compra se produce un error de que ya existe un registro con ese identificador.

espero sus respuestas.

Comment: Añade un poco de código, tu pregunta es muy genérica, se mas claro con el problema que tienes

Answer (score 0):

En la misma libreria dice: Para guardar necesitas llamar `store($identifier)`donde identifier es una llave aleatoria, puede ser el usuario o id del usuario

```
Cart::store('username');

// To store a cart instance named 'wishlist'
Cart::instance('wishlist')->store('username');
```

Comment: gracias amigo por responder, si ya hice el insert con el id del usuario o el nombre pero cuando intento hacer otra insercion con el mismo dato este me devuelve error diciendo que ya existe un registro con este identificador.

Comment: Si ya existe entonces no deberías crearlo de nuevo, deberías restaurarlo de la base de datos, para eso usa `Cart::restore('username');` y ya sobre eso hacer las modificaciones

Comment: lo que estaba pensando era obtener ese identificador de una tabla order, el si deberia cambiar cada vez que el usuario realizara una compra. Esa podria ser la solucion, ya despues me faltaria mostrar eso en la vista del administrador